# Replace everything that is not a letter,single quote,comma,period,question mark, or exclamation mark

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace everything that's not a letter,single quote,comma,period,question mark, or exclamation mark. But my regex expression doesn't seem to be working correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
$userResponse = "i'm so happy that you're here with me! :)";
$userResponse = preg_replace("~(?!['\,\.\?\!a-zA-Z]+)~", "", $userResponse);

echo $userResponse;
```

**Result:**

```
i'm so happy that you're here with me! :)
```

**Need Result:**

```
i'm so happy that you're here with me!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what you are doing with `(?!['\,\.\?\!a-zA-Z]+)`.

What your regex means is ***Look ahead if multiple characters mentioned in class, if present then match zero width after it.***

So your regex will look for **allowed characters** and match **zero width** since you are using `negative look ahead`.

[Dotted lines in test string is zero width.](https://regex101.com/r/nI8sP6/2)

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `[^a-zA-Z',.?!\s]`

**Explanation:** This regex matches **anything** except characters mentioned in class and is replaced by `empty string`.

**Php code:**

```
<?php
  $userResponse = "i'm so happy that you're here with me! :)";
  $userResponse = preg_replace("~[^a-zA-Z',.?!\s]~", "", $userResponse);
  echo $userResponse;
?>
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nI8sP6/1)**

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/N2G5XM)**

Answer (score 2):

Just try this one :

```
[^a-zA-Z',.?! ]+
```

Comment: adding a plus at the end of ] would make it a tiny bit faster right?